# How to cut a string that is a value of an array in 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this array that has `length = 3`:

```js
 state = ["q0", "q1", "q2,q3"]
```

And I want to modify that, and I want it to look something like this:

```js
 state = ["q0", "q1", "q2", "q3"] // length = 4.
```

I want to cut the `string = "q2,q3"` in a way that I will get `"q2"` and `"q3"` so that I can replace the `state[2]` value with `"q2"` and automatically add to the array like `state[3] = "q3"`.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

I tried the `split` method but it didn't work as I wanted.

Comment: `state.join(",").split(",")` will do the trick. However, this really should be solved at the source of the data.

Answer (score 2):

flatMap is perfect for this.

```
["q0", "q1", "q2,q3"].flatMap(v => v.split(','))
```

flatMap maps and then flattens. So mapping using split gives you `[['q0'], ['q1'], ['q2', 'q3']]`, then flattening unwraps each second-level array.

Answer (score 0):

One simple, and frankly naive, means of achieving this:

```js
// initial state, chained immediately to
// Array.prototype.map() to create a new Array
// based on the initial state (["q0", "q1", "q2, q3"]):
let state = ["q0", "q1", "q2, q3"].map(
  // str is a reference to the current String of the Array
  // (the variable name is free to be changed to anything
  // of your preference):
  (str) => {
    // here we create a new Array using String.prototype.split(','),
    // which splits the string on each ',' character:
    let subunits = str.split(',');
    
    // if subunits exists, and has a length greater than 1,
    // we return a new Array which is formed by calling
    // Array.prototype.map() - again - and iterating over
    // each Array-element to remove leading/trailing white-
    // space with String.prototype.trim(); otherwise
    // if the str is either not an Array, or the length is
    // not greater than 1, we return str:
    return subunits && subunits.length > 1 ? subunits.map((el) => el.trim()) : str;
  // we then call Array.prototype.map():
  }).flat();

// and log the output:
console.log(state);
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Conditional ("ternary") operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over `state`, try to split each value and then push them to res array.

```
const state = ["q0", "q1", "q2,q3"];

const res = [];

state.forEach((value) => {
  const splitValue = value.split(",");
  res.push(...splitValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using three javascript methods. `forEach()`, `concat()`, and `split()`. One liner

```
let result = []

state.forEach(a => result = result.concat(a.split(",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let state = ["q0", "q1", "q2,q3"];
state=state.join(',');
state=state.split(',');
console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I gave an example with gets the gap in the last index and splits it

```js
let deneme = ["first","second","third fourth"];


let index = deneme[2].indexOf(" ");  // Gets the first index where a space occours
let firstPart = deneme[2].slice(0, index); // Gets the first part
let secondPart = deneme[2].slice(index + 1);

console.log("first try" ,deneme);
deneme[2] = firstPart;
deneme.push(secondPart);
console.log("second look",deneme);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per @TrevorDixon's solution, `Array#flatMap` is the way to go. In case you have multiple separators you can use a regular expression with `String#split` as in the following demo:

```js
const
    input = ["q0", "q1", "q2,q3","q4 q5| q6"],
    
    output = input.flatMap(v => v.split(/[ ,|]+/));
    
console.log( output );
```